# Appcelerator: Android Window not full screen with top and bottom ~2% still showing the splash screen

Tags: appcelerator

I am running into this problem on all my apps. It is persistent across all OS versions. Screenshots below to see what the issue is. There are bars on top and bottom of the window where the splash screen is visible when the app is running.

```
var self = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
 title : 'Tab 1',
 backgroundColor : '#fff',
 fullscreen : true,
 backgroundImage : "/images/homeBG.png",
 orientationModes : [Titanium.UI.PORTRAIT],
});
self.open();
```

custom_theme.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.Titanium">
    <!-- Depending on the parent theme, this may be called android:windowActionBar instead of windowActionBar -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">2dp</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

[Splash Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBIbS.png)

[App Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ab9Ji.png) (You can see at the top and bottom where the splash screen is still visible)

Answer (score 1):

Remove these two attributes from custom_theme.xml:

```
<item name="android:paddingBottom">2dp</item>
<item name="android:paddingTop">2dp</item>
```

And try to work out on text-fields in their xml/tss file as I am sure that I have never needed to change the padding through theme file and it can definitely be done from xml/tss.

If you like, then you can share the actual problem of text-fields so that people can help you on that.

Comment: I asked the text field specific question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488989/appcelerator-android-textfield-bottom-and-top-padding-too-large-unable-to-chan):

Comment: what's the issue with textfield, is it UI related or something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
<item name="android:paddingBottom">2dp</item>
<item name="android:paddingTop">2dp</item>
```

Seems to be the problem, however I used this to change the padding on my text fields as they didn't display correctly without it. I will have to find another way to make the UI work